# How to resolve MS Access SQL UPDATE syntax error

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to type a SQL query in MS Access to update the records in FilesTable.FilePath with the records in Files.FPath, when the FilesTable.FileName Matches a record in Files.FName, but I receive an error:

```
UPDATE FilesTable
SET FilesTable.[FilePath] = Files.[FPath]
FROM (FilesTable INNER JOIN Files ON (FilesTable.[FileName] = Files.[FName])
WHERE *;
```

> syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Files.[FPath]
>       FROM (FilesTable INNER JOIN Files ON (FilesTable.[FileName] = Files.[FName])
>       WHERE *;'

I have also tried to add () after `Set` as well which results in an error as well:

```
UPDATE FilesTable
SET (FilesTable.[FilePath] = Files.[FPath])
FROM (FilesTable INNER JOIN Files ON (FilesTable.[FileName] = Files.[FName])
WHERE *;
```

> Syntax Error in UPDATE Statement.

[Here is how my tables looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4fMb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct query:

```
UPDATE FilesTable
INNER JOIN Files ON (FilesTable.FileName = Files.FName)
SET FilesTable.FilePath = Files.FPath
```

Comment: I get "Syntax Error in UPDATE Statement." again

Comment: lol i just did that and came here to say this is what i did, thanks man